# "A Crash Course in Lagrangian Dynamics". Is it still available online?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, specific-reference

In an Amazon review of "Schaum's Outline of Lagrangian Dynamics" I found [this](http://www.amazon.com/review/R1OP6ULYOYDI23/#R1OP6ULYOYDI23):

> *I recommend that you type ["Lagrangian Dynamics"](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=&as_epq=lagrangian+dynamics) into Google and look at some of the excellent sets of lecture notes available on-line. The online tutorial ["A Crash Course in Lagrangian Dynamics"](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=&as_epq=a+crash+course+in+lagrangian+dynamics) is particularly helpful. At only 18 pages it gets to the heart of the matter and contains some solved numerical examples.*

This intrigues me, but following his advice doesn't give the tutorial, save for a couple of incredibly dodgy looking download sites.

Anyone got any ideas on how I can get hold of it?

Comment: Sorry - This is a website for physics questions, not for obtaining specific sources (of physics material). Good luck in your search, but this is off-topic here.

Comment: FYI @Danu and others the relevant policy is [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4490/how-should-we-handle-how-to-find-a-reference-requests)

Comment: @DavidZ - it wasn't a paywall question, it was an existence problem.

Comment: @AppliedImagination OK, but I think this policy applies anyway. It covers all questions where you are trying to find the _content_ of the reference, not just those where the reference is paywalled. (To be clear, I'm arguing that based on the meta post I linked, this question is actually on topic here.)

Comment: I concur with DavidZ, this post is well within the bounds of on-topicness. The 3 close-votes are not justified, IMO.

Comment: I deleted some inappropriate comments and the associated discussion. Please remember that civility is expected at all times on this site; this is an official warning that rudeness will not be tolerated.

Answer (score 1):

Not the exact title, but stripping some non-essential bits of the search to *crash course lagrangian dynamics pdf*, I found a 12-page document titled *Crash Course in Discrete Lagrangian Dynamics* ([found here](http://hoj201academic.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/hoj_disc_lag_mech_tut.pdf)). This is likely *not* what you are looking for, but it could be useful nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks. That looks interesting. You've been really helpful.I can't upvote you, but consider yourself upvoted... :-)